# R dplyr to calculate first difference within 2 groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with 3 variables. Two are are factor variables( Policy_num and presidentnumber). The 3rd variables is a continues value (pred). I would like to create a new variable that is the first difference of pred foreach presidentnumber and Policy_num. The following code works but produces for me just the first difference of pred by presidentnumber. The dataframe is named dydx. This seems so simple and yet, I'm stumped.

```
newobject2 = dydx %>%
   group_by(Policy_num,presidentnumber) %>%
   mutate(dydx2 = pred-lag(pred))
```

produces this:

```
   ob Polic_num    Pres    pred     dydx2
   1 SocialWelfare Reagan  5.215365  NA
   2 SocialWelfare Reagan  4.373108 -0.8422576
   3 Agriculture   Reagan  5.180910  0.8078020
   4 Agriculture   Reagan  4.338652 -0.8422576
   5 Commerce      Reagan  5.206816  0.8681638
   6 Commerce      Reagan  4.364558 -0.8422576
```

It should look like this:

```
ob Polic_num    Pres    pred     dydx2
 1 SocialWelfare Reagan  5.215365  NA
 2 SocialWelfare Reagan  4.373108 -0.8422576
 3 Agriculture   Reagan  5.180910  NA
 4 Agriculture   Reagan  4.338652 -0.8422576
 5 Commerce      Reagan  5.206816  NA
 6 Commerce      Reagan  4.364558 -0.8422576
```

Here is code for verifiable example.

```
 presidentnumber = c("Reagan", "Reagan", "Reagan", "Reagan", "Bush", "Bush", 
 "Bush", "Bush", "Clinton", "Clinton", "Clinton", "Clinton")
 Policy_num=c("Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Social", "Social","Agriculture", 
 "Agriculture", "Social", "Social","Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Social", 
 "Social")
 pred=seq(1:12)
 ND=as.data.frame(cbind.data.frame(presidentnumber, Policy_num, pred))

 newobject4=ND %>%
   group_by(Policy_num, presidentnumber ) %>% 
   mutate(dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred)))
```

What this produces is this:

```
  Obs presidentnum Policy_num pred dydx2
  1   Reagan       Agriculture 1   NA
  2   Reagan       Agriculture 2   1
  3   Reagan       Social      3   1
  4   Reagan       Social      4   1
  5   Bush         Agriculture 5   1
  6   Bush         Agriculture 6   1
  7   Bush         Social      7   1
  8   Bush         Social      8   1
  9   Clinton      Agriculture 9   1
 10   Clinton      Agriculture 10  1
 11   Clinton      Social      11  1
 12   Clinton      Social      12  1
```

However, every other 1 above should be NA.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "first difference of pred"? Is it just `pred[2] - pred[1]` in each group? If so, then `dydx %>% group_by( Policy_num, presidentnumber ) %>% summarize( dydx2 = pred[2] - pred[1] )` should work. It would also help to see [exemplar data and expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the second observation in each group-first observation in each group. Your code produced one observation. I just need to generalize it for the rest of the obs. Essentially, the output above should have NA where the positive values are.

Comment: have a look at the link which @ArtemSokolov provided. Please provide example data. Also, you may want to generalise your question. It helps to understand a question when using simple variable names such as 'a' and 'b'

Comment: You might be running into some masking issues between `stats::lag()` and `dplyr::lag()`, as discussed [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772134/dplyr-how-to-lag-by-group). Try replacing `pred - lag(pred)` with `pred - dplyr::lag(pred)`, which explicitly uses the correct function.

Comment: Another potentially relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by

Comment: Lastly, an alternative to `x - lag(x)` is `diff(x)`. I just tried it on some mock data, and it seems to work fine: `dydx %>% group_by( ... ) %>% mutate( dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred)) )`

Comment: I tried replacing the code with pred - dplyr::lag(pred), but got the same result.

Comment: using      %>% mutate( dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred)) )      gave me the exact same output.

Comment: Hmm... can you please put together an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without exemplar data, it's hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: Working on it. The other thing I tried was to create a new grouping variable that was the interaction of the two factor variables I am trying to group by, and group by that single new variable instead, but I still got the same result. There are numbers where there should be NAs.

Comment: May you had loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr`.  After the group_by step try `%>% dplyr::mutate(dydx2 =`

Comment: No, its not that. I only have dplyr loaded.

Comment: I added MCVE code above.

Comment: I thought I figured it out. But I didn't. I submitted an answer, but it isn't correct. I thought using arrange() was necessary but it isn't.

Comment: Seems like this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when I take your verifiable code as:

```
require(dplyr)
newobject4 <- ND %>% group_by(Policy_num, presidentnumber ) %>% mutate(dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred)))

newobject4
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Policy_num, presidentnumber [6]
   presidentnumber Policy_num   pred dydx2
   <fct>           <fct>       <int> <int>
 1 Reagan          Agriculture     1    NA
 2 Reagan          Agriculture     2     1
 3 Reagan          Social          3    NA
 4 Reagan          Social          4     1
 5 Bush            Agriculture     5    NA
 6 Bush            Agriculture     6     1
 7 Bush            Social          7    NA
 8 Bush            Social          8     1
 9 Clinton         Agriculture     9    NA
10 Clinton         Agriculture    10     1
11 Clinton         Social         11    NA
12 Clinton         Social         12     1
```

And then:

```
require(plyr); require(dplyr)
newobject4 <- ND %>% group_by(Policy_num, presidentnumber ) %>% mutate(dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred)))
newobject4
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Policy_num, presidentnumber [6]
   presidentnumber Policy_num   pred dydx2
   <fct>           <fct>       <int> <int>
 1 Reagan          Agriculture     1    NA
 2 Reagan          Agriculture     2     1
 3 Reagan          Social          3     1
 4 Reagan          Social          4     1
 5 Bush            Agriculture     5     1
 6 Bush            Agriculture     6     1
 7 Bush            Social          7     1
 8 Bush            Social          8     1
 9 Clinton         Agriculture     9     1
10 Clinton         Agriculture    10     1
11 Clinton         Social         11     1
12 Clinton         Social         12     1
```

The suggestion above in the comments that you may have loaded `plyr` prior to `dplyr` could be true, and could be indirectly true. There may be another package dependent on `plyr` that you have loaded prior to `dplyr`. To fix this use:

```
newobject4 <- ND %>% group_by(Policy_num, presidentnumber ) %>% dplyr::mutate(dydx2 = c(NA, diff(pred))) 
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Policy_num, presidentnumber [6]
   presidentnumber Policy_num   pred dydx2
   <fct>           <fct>       <int> <int>
 1 Reagan          Agriculture     1    NA
 2 Reagan          Agriculture     2     1
 3 Reagan          Social          3    NA
 4 Reagan          Social          4     1
 5 Bush            Agriculture     5    NA
 6 Bush            Agriculture     6     1
 7 Bush            Social          7    NA
 8 Bush            Social          8     1
 9 Clinton         Agriculture     9    NA
10 Clinton         Agriculture    10     1
11 Clinton         Social         11    NA
12 Clinton         Social         12     1
```

Comment: That worked for me! That's so weird because I don't even have plr loaded as a library.... Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may have another packaged dependent on `plyr` loaded.