# How do I lag Quarters in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

First and foremost - thank you for viewing my question - regardless of if you answer or not.

I am trying to add a column that contains the lagged values of the Quarter value to my DF, however, I get the below warning when I do so:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
 Vectorizing 'yearqtr' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

Below is my sample data (my data starts on 1/3/2018)

```
Ticker  Price   Date      Quarter
  A       10    1/3/18    2018 Q1
  A       13.5  2/15/18   2018 Q1
  A       12.9  4/2/18    2018 Q2
  A       11.2  5/3/18    2018 Q2
  B       35.2  1/4/18    2018 Q1
  B       33.1  3/2/18    2018 Q1
  B       31    4/6/18    2018 Q2
 ...      ...   ...        ...
  XYZ     102    5/6/18   2018 Q2
```

I have a huge table with multiple stocks and multiple dates. The way I calculate the quarter column is :

```
df$quarter <- lag(as.yearqtr(df$Date))
```

But however - I can't get to add a column that would lag the values of the Quarter. Would anyone know a possible workaround?

I would like the below output:

```
Ticker  Price   Date      Quarter  Lag_Q
  A       10    1/3/18    2018 Q1   NA
  A       13.5  2/15/18   2018 Q1   NA
  A       12.9  4/2/18    2018 Q2   2018 Q1
  A       11.2  5/3/18    2018 Q2   2018 Q1
  B       35.2  1/4/18    2018 Q1   NA
  B       33.1  3/2/18    2018 Q1   NA
  B       31    4/6/18    2018 Q2   2018 Q1
 ...      ...   ...        ...
  XYZ     102    5/6/18   2018 Q2   2018 Q1
```

Comment: Is your data frame grouped when you try adding the `Lag_Q` column? See this issue: https://github.com/business-science/sweep/issues/5

Comment: Looks like you just want the lag done by `Ticker` group? If so, you can use `library(dplyr);
df %>% 
  group_by(Ticker) %>% 
  mutate(Lag_Q = lag(Quarter)) %>% 
  ungroup`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772134/dplyr-how-to-lag-by-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest organizing your data so that each column represents prices of an individual security and each row is a specific date. From there, you can transform all securities easily, but I'm not sure what your end goal is. The `xts` package is excellent and has been optimized in `c`, and is kind of the securities industry standard. I highly suggest exploring it. But that's beyond the scope of your post!

For your data structure though, a single line should do:

```
df$lag_Q <- as.yearqtr( ifelse(test = (df$quarter=="2018 Q1"), 
                                yes = NA, 
                                 no = df$quarter-0.25) )
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. this does work. I'll make sure I read up on xts package for sure. Thanks Justin!

Comment: Anytime! Another good suggestion for learning from SO posts, if your not under a deadline (and who isn't these days?), I'd look up the documentation of ifelse, as.yearqtr, and data.frame to understand the rules of the functions and classes in greater depth. Once you know the constraints which govern them all, a path forward becomes clearer. Good luck!